# Retrieving information from google page

Tags: android, database, cloud, extract, information-retrieval

I'm thinking about making my first android app, It'd be about movies, I found an excellent data source, it is "http://www.google.com/movies?" but I wanted to know how could I extract this information and put it in my app,

I've searched but I don't know which is the optimal way to do this? does google have an API for this? is that what I want? is it better with the source code?what could I read or see to learn to do this?

thanks a lot guys, Is my first time as well programming retrieving information from the cloud,

cheers

Comment: TheMovieDB, Rotten Tomatoes... doesn't work for me 'cus it doesn't give me information about schedules and locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Here is one way to do it.

First, you need to find the source of the SQL. The Yahoo Developer Console is a great place to look for this sort of stuff. It has EVERYTHING. The way these resources work is that you have a long link, like this....
developer.yahoo.com/blah/this . . . &q=KEYWORD_HERE+blah/ . . .

To access the information you are looking for, you stick whatever the correct keyword is where "KEYWORD_HERE" is, and the link will give you info in SQL format. I'll be doing the example as a stocks app.

First you create an Activity and define both sides of your link as strings. It'll look a bit like this:

```
public class InfoActivity extends Activity {
       String firstHalf = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/blahblahblah&q=";
       String secondHalf = "+blah/blah&blah . . . ";
```

Then, in your onCreate, you'll need to start an aSync task to do the actual pulling and parsing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
       super.onCreate(bundle);
       setContentView(R.id.layout_name);
       final String yqlURL = firstHalf + KEYWORD_HERE + secondHalf; 
       new MyAsyncTask().execute(yqlURL);
}
```

Then to define our MrAsyncTask:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                  URL url = new URL(args[0]);
                  URLConnection connection;
                  connection = url.openConnection();

                  HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;

                  int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();


                  // Tests if responseCode == 200 Good Connection
                 if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document dom = db.parse(in);

                    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

                    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("nodeName1");

                    if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {


                      for (int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

                        //Parse the node here with getTextValue(n1, "Name of element")
                        //ex: String movieName = getTextValue(n1, "MovieName");

                      }
                    }
                  }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "IOException", e);
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Parser Configuration Exception", e);
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "SAX Exception", e);
                }
                finally {
                }

            return null;
        }
```

I hope that gives you some idea of how to do this sort of thing. I'll go see if I can quickly spot a good resource on the yahoo apis to get the movie times at a certain location.

Good luck :) Let me know if you need anything clarified.

EDIT:
Looks like this is EXACTLY what you need (resource wise):
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+google.igoogle.movies+where+movies%3D'68105'%3B

Check that out. Using that, your two halves of the link would be:

```
String firstHalf = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20google.igoogle.movies%20where%20movies%3D'"

String secondHalf = "'%3B&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"
```

And then to get your final link, you would just do

```
String yqlURL = firstHalf + "ZIP CODE OF YOUR LOCATION" + secondHalf;
```

And you would have all of the movies playing near you returned!

Comment: thanks for your answer, I finishing using JSoup, this is great too, but a bit more complicated for me

Comment: No problem. There are a million ways to do it, to be honest!

Answer (score 0):

Make your life a lot easier and choose the api that is right for you.  Choose one of these:

http://www.programmableweb.com/news/52-movies-apis-rovi-rotten-tomatoes-and-internet-video-archive/2013/01/22

Make your decision not only based on the content, but also ease of use and documentation.  Documentation is a biggy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

well i would rather advice you to use an [TheMovieDB.com API](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) it is simple and provides every info of movies.